# Changing label color of a label in a different view (delegates?) [Spritebuilder]

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, delegates

I have two scenes that I made in SpriteBuilder, one is Shop and the other is UpgradesNew. Shop is a CCNode layer and UpgradesNew is a CCNode layer. I have two CCScrollViews in the MainScene that load Shop and UpgradesNew respectively.

When one button in Shop is tapped, the label in UpgradesNew should change colors. I have been trying to implement this using delegates but it's not working.

Here's what I did...

In shop.h I set the protocol:

```
@protocol changeColorProtocol <NSObject>
@required
     -(void)changeColor;
@end
```

Then I set the id

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id <changeColorProtocol> delegate;
```

Here is the button that when clicked, should use changeColor. This is in shop.m

```
-(void) buyDiggerShibe {
        [self.delegate changeColor];
        [self didLoadFromCCB];
}
```

Now in UpgradesNew.h I made it adopt the protocol like this

```
@interface UpgradesNew : CCNode <changeColorProtocol>
```

And in UpgradesNew.m

I set delegate to self in ViewDidLoad.

```
Shop *shop = [[Shop alloc]init];
shop.delegate = self;
```

.

```
-(void)changeColor {
    if (hasDigger == YES) {
        shovelRequires.color = [CCColor greenColor];
        NSLog(@"HEY HEY HEY");
    }
}
```

I probably have parts of the delegate placed in the wrong area because I was trying to switch them around when it wasn't working, I'm not sure where they are supposed to go. I've watched multiple delegate tutorials and it just seems overly complicated, at least with what I am trying to do.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Tried this.

I created a property in UpgradesNew

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Shop *shop;
```

Then I synthesized it in the implementation and allocated it like this in didLoadFromCCB, instead of creating a new object:

```
self.shop = [[Shop alloc]init];
shop.delegate = self;
```

EDIT: This is how I am creating objects.

Drag a label into a layer. [Identify it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAYco.jpg) then define it in header as `CCLabelTTF *label;` That's it, thats all I do to create any object on the layer.

To create a layer like Shop or UpgradesNew, I hit [New -> File -> Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lurZf.jpg). That creates a new CCNode. Then I set the class of the CCNode, as shown in the picture the CCNode that is highlighted has a class of MainScene. If I want to establish a @property to that CCNode I just type the name in the box right below custom class and set it as doc root var, and then put it in the header as `CCNode *MainScene`. I don't do anything other than that.

Comment: Is this another approach to the same problem you were posting about yesterday and fail to provide and clear, meaningful information to help answer your question?

Comment: @nhgrif yes it is, because everyone stopped replying so I tried to find a solution. I don't see what other information you would need. Initialization is done via SpriteBuilder. I preface my other questions like this and most people are able to help.

Comment: This code has the EXACT same problem as yesterday.  Rather than using a reference to an existing object, you're creating a new object and using that.  Yesterday you were calling a method on the new object--today you're trying to set the new object as a delegate.

Comment: You need to work through some very simple OOP tutorials.  Your problem is obvious--even you admitted you knew what the problem was, but because you don't understand OOP concepts well enough, you don't even know what to include in your question in order for someone to type out the code you need to copy-paste into your project.

Comment: @nhgrif I updated the original post

Comment: This change merely changes the scope of the variable.  It doesn't actually change what you're doing.  You need a reference to the object you want to change, not to just any object that happens to be of the same time.

Comment: @nhgrif For the reference, I have `CCLabelTTF *label;` in implementation so I am using that. [I read this](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html) and that was a good tutorial for properties and references, and I'm going to look at his other stuff too. What tutorials should I look at specifically for what I need? I know you said OOP, but I don't know if I am thinking about the right thing when you say to make a reference to the object. I also have edited a bit more into my post that hopefully explains some

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about SpriteBuilder, so it's a bit hard to address your question. You might want to add SpriteBuilder to the title of your post so people who use that framework are likely to read it.

You need to explain how the 2 "CCNode layer"s are created, and how you link them together. In order for one object to have another object as a delegate, the delegate property has to be set somewhere. Where is that setup being done? Have you set a breakpoint at the line

```
[self.delegate changeColor];
```

To make sure that `self.delegate` is not nil?

Have you set a breakpoint in your changeColor method, or added a log statement, to see if it's being called? My guess is that self.delegate is nil, so the messages is being dropped on the floor (it's legal to send messages to nil in Objective-C. It just doesn't do anything.)

Comment: Duncan, it's not nil: `Shop *shop = [[Shop alloc]init];
shop.delegate = self;`.  Problem is pretty obvious, right?  He has the same problem yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025776/changing-label-color-of-a-label-in-a-different-layer

Comment: Yeah it's not being called, I have an NSLog in there. I updated my post, instead of creating a new object I referenced the already existing Shop (hopefully did this correctly). Since I'm using SpriteBuilder and I'm still really new to obj-c I honestly don't know where SB puts the things it does to create the layer.

Comment: Albert, address the other things I asked for in my answer.

Comment: Based on nhgrif's reference to your other post, it sounds like you're creating a new Shop object and setting the delegate on that, rather than on an existing Shop object. Don't abandon another question on the same subject and start a new thread. When somebody more experienced gives you information, pursue it, and follow up in the same thread. Otherwise you will run out of goodwill with the people who can best help you.

Comment: The delegate property is being set in UpgradeNew's didLoadFromCCB, as `shop.delegate = self;` As far as linking the two together, that's what I am stuck on right now. I figured out that I (think) I need to declare the @property of both the CCNodes in their respective classes. In the edit code, I had `@property (nonatomic, retain) Shop *shop;` in UpgradesNew header instead of Shop header.

Comment: Not enough information by a long shot. Post a complete description of what you are doing as an edit to your question. Describe the sequence of how the different objects are being created and linked together, and show all the relevant code.

Comment: @DuncanC Ok I just updated the OP and explained exactly what I do with pictures. Nothing else is being done to create objects than what I have in the last edit.

Comment: @DuncanC Any ideas? I don't know where SB instantiates it in the code, and looking it up failed to provide an answer. Maybe I am searching for the wrong terms

Comment: @DuncanC [I found a nearly identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454043/change-label-text-color-using-delegate) He is actually having the same problem as I am. His updateLabel isn't being called, just like my changeColor isn't being called.

Comment: @DuncanC This is why I created a new post. Nobody replies.